# SQLlite3 - Incorrect number of bindings supplied error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

In Sqlite3 I am getting the following error while inserting. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```py
lessons = [('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('10'),('11'),('12'),('13'),('14'),('15'),('16'),('17'),('18'),('19'),('20'),('21'),('22'),('23'),('24'),('25'),('26'),('27'),('28'),('29'),('30'),('31')]

cursor.executemany('''
    INSERT INTO lessons (lessondt) VALUES
    (?)
''', lessons)
```

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Answer (score 1):

`('1')` is not a tuple, it's just `'1'`. To make a tuple with one element it needs to end in a comma, i.e. `('1',)`. Same for all the other elements.

Rather create the values with a list comprehension.

```
lessons = [(str(i),) for i in range(1, 32)]
```